# How to define a generic value ranges (include open ranges) for a generic Binary Search Tree validation with keys of an arbitrary type

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, binary-search-tree, generic-programming

Binary Search Tree validation needs min and max range before starting the validation from the root node.

below is my code to do it for Integer.

```
 public boolean checkBST(Node root) {
    int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    return validateBST(root, min, max);
  }
```

Reference : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Verification

As the validation progresses down the tree the valid range is norrowed depending on the value found at the subtree node. However for the verify top node I need to specify a range that would accept any value.

This is easy with numeric primitive type wrappers like `Integer` (example above) or `Double` if you commit to a specific element type. However I need to generalize this approach so that it works with any given `T` type (it could be a `Number`, or something completely different).

We can assume that `T` is a `Comparable<? extends T>` or that an appropriate Comparator is passed when the tree is constructed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Post `validateBST()`. Are you trying to verify that a value is within a range ? What are the valid types of this value ? any number ?

Comment: I have created BinarySearchTree with Node<Q> , Q of any type. for Integer, I know the min and max range allowed while verifying the BST. What about a double, String, Character or Object of custom type. How to implement validate BST for any Type.

Comment: "how does a min and max range makes sense for any Custom Type. say., Employee, Names" It is up to you to decide how to compare and decide which is bigger, and implement `compareTo` in those objects. For example make [Employee compareable](https://howtodoinjava.com/sort/sort-arraylist-objects-comparable-comparator/). If you know to compare those objects you can define  min max.

Comment: Not sure what are you asking for here... if you want us to generalize that piece of code in the question I guess what you are actually asking to obtain the absolute maximum or minimum of any given Type... the answer is simply impossible because there is no guarantee that there is such a thing as a +/- "Infinite" for an arbitrary type T. For example Strings.... the maximum string is the infinite size string which you cannot instantiate. What could be done is that you create a Range class that optionally allows you to indicate that there are not upper or lower limit in your range.

Comment: I think that now I'm getting what you are asking for, I suspect  that  is asking the generic version of Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE for any given ```T``` not just ```int```s so something like ```T.MIN_VALUE``` and ```T.MAX_VALUE```. I have to say that you question does not make it very clear, perhaps you should consider to reword it. I have submitted an answer that addresses such concern to the best of my ability.

Comment: "I suspect that is asking the generic version of Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE for any given T " I do not think it is practically needed. You could iterate over the entire graph find min, max values and use those values.

Comment: Traverse the binary search tree once to get min and max range is a cool idea. If i can maintain a state and modify it while every insert into BST - I can avoid this minmax while every validation of BST.

Comment: @c0der That seems very costly when you simply can use nulls to signal that any value is acceptable if that is the intention.

Comment: @ValentinRuano I do not think that that is the intention. There are too many speculations on what is the question here. It is a badly put question which causes all of us waste time guessing.

Comment: @c0der updated my question - feel free to update instead of downvoting.

Comment: @SundarRajan I edited your question to make it more clear, feel free to edit back for probable typos or if I misunderstood what you are after.

Comment: @SundarRajan by the way I notice that my solution does not work because the +1 -1 operation is not defined for ```T```. However the fix is easy... the ranges are exclusive in either side, so the limit of the ranges are not considered part of the range, unfortunately it is less intuitive but there is not work around for a generic ```T``` solution. I will update the answer eventually.

Comment: @SundarRajan in any case the new solution would work with BST that do not have repeated keys as in the link that you posted. To get it to work with repeated keys you can make the ranges to include their limits.

Comment: @ValentinRuano Yes, +1 -1 operation not needed If duplicates are fine atleast in one side. I mean left <= root < right.   btw , T.getValue() where this contract comes from.

Comment: Finding min or max once traversing all the nodes is NOT costly. anyhow, for validation I am doing theta(n) order, so 2 more operations is fair enough. I don't find any better approach. Also if you see the problem carefully, min and max range are not just needed for Initial root. Max remains constant in the right & Min remains constant in the left.

Comment: It is true that the complexity does not increase, if the tree is balance the max or min should be O(log n) but it is not necessary. Also you could keep track on the min and max as values are inserted. You have your options

Answer (score 1):

To compare objects you need them to implement `Comparable` so define your node type to be a subclass of `Comparable` :

```
class Node<Q extends Comparable<Q>>{

    private final Q value;
    private Node left, right;   

    Node getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    Node getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    Node(Q value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    Q getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

When `Q` implements comparable you can compare two objects, for example:

```
Node<String> minNode = new Node<>("Z");
Node<String> maxNode = new Node<>("A");
Node<String> aNode = new Node<>("L");
System.out.println(aNode.getValue().compareTo(minNode.getValue())< 0 &&
                            aNode.getValue().compareTo(maxNode.getValue()) > 0 );
```

Being able to compare, you should be able to define `boolean isBST(Node node, Node minNode, Node maxNode)`

**Edit:**
If your question is about "generic version of Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE for any given T": 
I do not think it is practically needed. You could iterate over the entire graph find min, max values and use those values.

Comment: I have implemented Comparable already  and can use compareTo for any object type. Now here you are saying "Z" and "A" which is not the practical limit for a String.  My problem is NOT how to perform compare , my problem how do you define min and max range generic across any data type.

Comment: what if BST of strings contains "@TestValue" , clearly the bounded defined won't work.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) implements `Comparable` so you can compare any two strings.

Comment: minNode = new Node<String> ("A");  what about a string "a" or anything less than that.  If my BST has the following inputs that should be assembled as BST tree. "__a", "@b" , "1abc" etc.

Comment: for a Custom Class like 'Address' , i can compareTo on a specific primitive type or String and the minimum range to be defined on that. I am trying to make this class BST a generic class - should I have to code specific method to return min and max range depends on the type.

Comment: No, you only need to have the generic type implement `Compareable` hence `extends Comparable<Q>>`

Comment: Upvoting for "You could iterate over the entire graph find min, max values and use those values."

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you are asking how to figure out the absolute max or min value for any given type so that you can specify a range that would accept any value as valid.

Unfortunately in general an arbitrary `T` does not necessarily have an instantiable minimum and maximum. In fact `int` and `Integer` do only because due to representation limitation they cannot be arbitrarily large or small.

For example for `String` one can argue that then empty string ("") is the minimum, certainly is less or equal to any other `String` using its natural order but what would be the maximum string. It probably would an infinitely long repetition of the maximum unicode character, so you cannot create such an object.

However that should not stop you from being able to define ranges that would include any value or that they are open in one end (i.e. they have a min but not a max or viceversa).

For example if the range is to be specified as two arguments in the signature of the method that is going to use such a range then you can simply designate the `null` as to indicate that that min or max does not exist, that is that end of the range is open.

That seem to me that would work nicely with your `valideteBST` as it already has those two parameters.

```
class BST<T extends Comparable<T>> {
   // ...
   public boolean checkBST(Node<T> root) {
      return validateBST(root, null, null);
   }
   // ...
   boolean validateBST(Node<T> node, T min, T max) {
         if (node == null) {
            // nothing to do here.
            return true;
         }
         final T value = node.getValue();
         if (min != null && min.compareTo(value) >= 0) {
             return false;
         } else if (max != null && max.compareTo(value) <= 0) {
             return false;
         } else {
             return validateBST(node.getLeft(), min, value) &&
                    validateBST(node.getRight(), value, max);
         }
   }
   // ...
}
```

Now some people may not like visible use of `null` for this. In such case then you may need to define a `Range<T>` class that encapsulates it:

```
public class Range<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private T min;
    private T max;

    private Range(T min, T max) {
       this.min = min;
       this.max = max;
    }

    public static <T> of(T min, T max) {
       Objects.requiresNonNull(min);
       Objects.requiresNonNull(max);
       return new Range(min, max);
    }

    public static <T> from(T min) {
       Objects.requiresNonNull(min);
       return new Range(min, null);
    }

    public static <T> to(T max) {
       Objects.requiresNonNull(max);
       return new Range(null, max);
    }

    public static <T> all() {
       return new Range(null, null);
    }

    public Range<T> subRangeTo(T max) {
       Objects.requiresNonNull(max);
       return new Range<>(this.min, max);
    }

    public Range<T> subRangeFrom(T min) {
       Objects.requiresNonNull(min);
       return new Range<>(min, this.max);
    }

    public boolean encloses(T value) {
       Objects.requiresNonNull(value);
       return (min == null || min.compareTo(value) < 0) 
            &&  (max == null || max.compareTo(value) > 0);
    }
}
```

Then the code in validate is more trivial:

```
   // ...
   public boolean checkBST(Node<T> root) {
     return validateBST(root, Range.all());
   }
   // ...
   boolean validateBST(Node<T> node, Range<T> range) {
         if (node == null) {
            return true;
         }
         if (!range.encloses(node.getValue)) {
            return false;
         } else {
            return validateBST(node.getLeft(), Range.subRangeTo(value)) 
                   && validateBST(node.getRight(), Range.subRangeFrom(value));
         }
   }
   // ...
```

Notice that the ranges in either solution do not include the limit values.

This is necessary for BST tree that do not have repeated keys. For tree with possible repeated keys you can make the approach work by making the range "enclosing" comparison to accept values are the same as its limits.

Alternatively nodes could hold the number of repeats to that key so the keys remain unique, that make more sense if most keys are going to be repeated.